# Editext Value Getting Null when I call from Activity to Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

**Activity -> Fragment**

I have a one button on my Activity. i want to get Value from Editext which is present in Fragment. when i call from Activity i get Null Value of Editext.

MainActivity.kt Code

```
buttonOne?.setOnClickListener {
        val frgment = MyFragment().getInstance()
        frgment?.buttonClick()
    }
```

MyFragment.kt Code

```
fun getInstance(): MyFragment? {
        return MyFragment()
    }

    fun buttonClick(){
        val value = et_fragment_first_name?.text.toString().trim()
        Log.e("Fragment", "FirstName $value")
}
```

Can anybody help me about it? I don't want to use Listner

Comment: well you can't do that , you cant access the variable and object presented on activity class yet you can access statically or use viewmodel to pass data see this https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate

Comment: Thank you Ananiya for your valuable comment. my issue solved by using instance of Fragment Tag name. You aware me about  ViewModel concept . i will try it with my new Project

Comment: glad to hear that @Sayed Rizwan Hashmi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you just did is that you created a new instance of the fragment instead of getting the instance of the current active fragment, that is why you are getting a null. You can use FragmentManager to get a fragment by tag or Id

`MyFragment myFragment = (MyFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MY_FRAGMENT");`

Comment: Thank You Very Very Much @Olamilenkan. its Working Now